# P&T Assets - old image selections returning

Tags: assets

I've recently upgraded a site to use Assets 2.3.2 instead of the built-in File field-type. This field is a column in a Matrix field.

During the process of setting the new field-type I did notice that there were a lot of very similar rows in the `exp_assets_selections` table like this:

```
INSERT INTO `exp_assets_selections` (`file_id`, `entry_id`, `field_id`, `col_id`, `row_id`, `var_id`, `element_id`, `content_type`, `sort_order`, `is_draft`)
VALUES
    (19, 3270, 26, 31, 44019, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
    (22678, 3270, 26, 31, 44019, NULL, NULL, 'matrix', 0, 0);
```

For some entries that are updated the old image will reappear and the new image selection will not seem to be remembered. The rows above are one such example of this happening.

Which row is the correct selection format and is it possible to delete the unwanted rows with SQL as a means to clean up the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Iain, sounds like a good case for emailing us at support@pixelandtonic.com!

Comment: Email sent :) .

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same problem on two sites. Updating Assets to 2.5 seems to solve the problem for us on both installations (so I guess this was a bug that's been fixed).